# Does Polymer allow a different definition of identity for data binding?

Tags: polymer

Based on the ["How data binding tracks template instances" section](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#how-data-binding-tracks-template-instances) in the Polymer Data Binding docs, it sounds like JavaScript equality is used to determine if the data is the "same" between template invocations. So value types have value equality, but objects and arrays use reference equality. If I make two calls to a service which returns an array of objects, and some of those objects have the same values between calls, the template instances will be recreated as both the array and objects are deserialized into different instances (I have verified this behavior in version 0.3.3).

Is it possible to specify an identity function similar to how [D3 employs a key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such a thing but I would come up with a different solution. Let's assume your code looks something like this (pseudocode)

```
<ajax onResponse="{{onResponse}}" response="{{ajaxResponse}}" url="/users"></ajax>
<template repeat="{{user in ajaxResponse}}">
   <span>Hello from {{user.name}}</span>
</template>
```

If I got you right, you said, that when the request is made the template get's reevaluated no matter if there were changes in the data or not.

To fix this, we can represent our data in a different way which evaluates not by reference but by value.

```
class UserListElement extends PolymerElement {

   @observable List userIds = toObservable([]);
   Map<int, Object> users = {};

   onResponse(var response) {
      users = {};
      for(var user in response) {
        users[user.id] = user;
        if (!users.contains(user.id)) userIds.add(user.id);
      }
      var toRemove = userIds.where((user) => !_userData.containsKey(user.id));
      for(var userId in toRemove) userIds.remove(userId);
   }
}
```

-

```
<ajax onResponse="{{onResponse}}" url="/users"></ajax>
<template repeat="{{userId in users}}">
   <span>Hello from {{users[userId].name}}</span>
</template>
```

As I said non-tested pseudocode. But this is the only idea I can come up with.